# Search Suggestion android

Tags: android, search, android-contentprovider

I'm using a `ContentProvider` for search suggestions but I have a problem for handling a suggestion click: I explain the search works good but when I click in suggestion I go to the search activity but the re isn't anything, so how can I handle a click suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML\searchable.xml (or equivalent) should include

```
android:searchSuggestIntentAction = android.intent.action.VIEW
```

otherwise your intent won't be called.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html defines this field as:

> The default intent action to be used when a user clicks on a custom
>   search suggestion (such as "android.intent.action.VIEW"). If this is
>   not overridden by the selected suggestion (via the
>   SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_ACTION column), this value is placed in the
>   action field of the Intent when the user clicks a suggestion.